# Dates from HSQL Database returns negative values in fastTime field

Tags: java, date, jdbc, hsqldb

im extracting dates from my HSQL database and they display correctly but internally they seem to be wrong. Most of the Dates are defaults with 1970-01-01 as its value. While debugging i can see a field called "fastTime" which says it is -3.600.000 which is exactly one minute before it should be...

When i now mix these dates up with some generated values where fastTime is 0 the comparison is wrong and the wrong date is picked.

This is extremly annoying because just adding the value when extractng it from DB works for now but switching to another DBMS would require to revert this changes.

So.. Is this just a bug or whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dates display correctly, then they are correct for your time zone.

If the fastTime indicates the value you are reporting, it means your time zone is GMT+1hour. If the fastTime was 0, then the date would represent midnight at GMT, rather than in your time zone.

Your need to account for time zone when you peform comparisons in Java between dates that belong to different zones. You can use a Java Calendar object for this purpose.

Comment: Well though this is a good tip - Why is it just one minute offset? If it was an hour it would fit your answer but not one minute this seems wrong to me.

Comment: 3600000 milliseconds is one hour, not one minute